# Cron job in AWS ec2 but it is not working

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron

I've created a cron job in AWS EC2 but it is not working.

I followed the below steps to create crontab:

```
Step 1: I logged in to AWS EC2 Instance.
step 2: crontab -e
Step 3: Insert mode
Step 4: I entered */5 * * * * php /var/www/html/task1.php
Step 5: :wq
```

Cron tab is created but not running.

**What I have tried?**

```
1. */5 * * * * php /var/www/html/task1.php
2. */5 * * * * /bin/php /var/www/html/task1.php
3. */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/task1.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But there is no luck using the above and also after saving these I have restarted the server as well -> **sudo systemctl restart apache2**

I have checked the logs and found the below message (last 100 lines, task1.php is just an example name but the original name is translate-audi.php, thanks for understanding).

```html
Sep 19 09:45:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52479]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 09:49:41 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52493]: (ubuntu) LIST (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:50:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52519]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 09:53:05 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52580]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:53:13 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52580]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:53:57 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52589]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:55:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52598]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 09:55:19 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52589]: (ubuntu) REPLACE (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:55:19 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52589]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:55:32 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 09:55:33 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 09:55:33 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 09:55:33 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 09:55:33 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 09:55:51 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52634]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:56:01 ip-172-31-30-156 cron[450]: (ubuntu) RELOAD (crontabs/ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:56:33 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52634]: (ubuntu) REPLACE (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:56:33 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52634]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:56:38 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52640]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:56:44 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52640]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:56:49 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52645]: (ubuntSep 19 09:56:49 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52645]: (ubuntu) LIST (ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:57:01 ip-172-31-30-156 cron[450]: (ubuntu) RELOAD (crontabs/ubuntu)
Sep 19 09:57:37 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 09:57:37 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 09:57:37 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 09:57:37 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 09:57:37 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 10:00:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52686]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:05:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52774]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:09:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52811]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Sep 19 10:09:32 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Sep 19 10:09:32 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 10:09:32 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Sep 19 10:10:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52879]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:15:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52907]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/autotranslate-dev-ec2/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:17:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52928]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 19 10:18:08 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52941]: (ubuntu) LIST (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:18:21 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52942]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:18:52 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52942]: (ubuntu) REPLACE (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:18:52 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52942]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:19:01 ip-172-31-30-156 cron[450]: (ubuntu) RELOAD (crontabs/ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:19:44 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52954]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:20:00 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[52954]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:20:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[52963]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:20:42 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 10:20:43 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 10:20:43 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 10:20:43 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 10:20:43 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 10:25:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53006]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:27:59 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53011]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:30:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53023]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 10:30:34 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53011]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:30:36 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53026]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:31:01 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53026]: (ubuntu) REPLACE (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:31:01 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53026]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:31:01 ip-172-31-30-156 cron[450]: (ubuntu) RELOAD (crontabs/ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:31:06 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53032]: (ubuntu) BEGIN EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:31:11 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53032]: (ubuntu) END EDIT (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:31:17 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 10:31:17 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 10:31:17 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 10:31:17 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 19 10:31:17 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Sep 19 10:35:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53072]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 10:35:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53069]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 10:39:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53086]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Sep 19 10:39:21 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Sep 19 10:39:21 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 10:39:21 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Sep 19 10:40:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53152]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 10:40:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53150]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 10:45:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53161]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 10:45:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53159]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 10:45:08 ip-172-31-30-156 systemd[1]: Started Session 37 of user ubuntu.
Sep 19 10:46:10 ip-172-31-30-156 crontab[53282]: (ubuntu) LIST (ubuntu)
Sep 19 10:50:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53293]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 10:50:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53290]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 10:55:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53309]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 10:55:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53308]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 11:00:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53320]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 11:00:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53318]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 11:05:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53338]: (ubuntu) CMD (php /var/www/html/translate-audi.php)
Sep 19 11:05:01 ip-172-31-30-156 CRON[53337]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Please can anyone help me if I am missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does your logs say?

Comment: I Am new to these things, could you please help me that how to get those details, I'll provide you the info right away.

Comment: I'm not sure of the configuration, check your `/var/logs` directory for either a `cron.log` or `syslog` file. Also, I don't recommend supressing your STDOUT to `/dev/null` unless you expect no output. Capture it in a log file for debug and purge it as and when required.

Comment: I have checked the folder but found these files.
alternatives.log,  
apache2,  
auth.log , 
cloud-init-output.log,  
dist-upgrade,  
dpkg.log,  
kern.log,   
lastlog,  
syslog,                
unattended-upgrades,
amazon,            
apt,      
btmp,      
cloud-init.log,         
dmesg,         
journal,   
landscape,  
private,  
ubuntu-advantage.log,  
wtmp

Comment: Yes, update your question with the most relevant content inside the `syslog` file using your favourite editor or `cat /var/logs/syslog` - this will tell you of any issues your `crontab` is having. If it is empty, I suggest you do not supress your `task1.php` output to `/dev/null` because it could be an issue with the PHP file itself. Instead, redirect it to a log file using `>>` instead of `>` to allow it to append.

Comment: Done bro, edited the issue.

Comment: So instantly you can see the CRON executing which means you can now look to debug your program. Redirect the STDOUT to a file and debug from there, it appears you may have issues within your `task1.php`. Post the error, along with your PHP code unless you can debug yourself.

Comment: Ho Jaquarh, i had tried above but no luck, here is the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gyf2PpamgFcaGWSE0XKnAdOet18L30Qd/view?usp=sharing

I have ran the script manually in the Ec2 it executed well without any issues.